# Python how to make datetime update time

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

Im using datetime with pytz, but i cant get time to update.

```
format = "[%B %d %H:%M]"
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
greece = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Athens'))
date = greece.strftime(format)
```

For example i print(date) at 11:30, it stays like that.
Any idea?

Comment: Functions like `datetime.now()`  are a bit weird because they give a different result every time you call them, unlike regular functions, whose returned values depend solely on the inputs you pass them. Now that weirdness is useful and necessary when interacting with the real world: not just for date and time, but also for  free memory, the size of a log file, etc. But if you want that sort of nondeterminism in your program, you have to explicitly ask for it by calling a function, rather than having a variable change its value behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, `date` remains the same throughout the runtime. There is nothing to update it at the current time. If you want to check and print the time at regular intervals, you need to define a function and have your script call it after that amount of time.

```
import time
fmt = "[%B %d %H:%M]"

def print_now()
     now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
     greece = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Athens'))
     date = greece.strftime(fmt)
     print(date)

while True:
     print_now()
     time.sleep(60)  # argument is time to wait in seconds
```

As long as `True` is `True` (which is always), the loop will continue, unless you define some condition to force it to end at some point. Of course, you could have the `print_now()` function contents within the `while` loop, but it's a bit cleaner to have it in it's own function.